# Can you await session state operations in .NET?

Tags: .net, async-await, session-state

I don't see a way to await session state operations in .NET. I realize that this would be pretty much useless and even worse, probably just adding overhead if the session state is stored in-proc however if the session state is persisted over the wire in a database, state machine or what have you it would be nice to await session state operations.

Comment: i'm lost...  examples?

Comment: Say you simply get session data from HttpContext.Current.Session[key]. This is not awaitable. This is synchronous. So if I'm not mistaken, this thread will block while waiting for the state-machine or db to return the results.

Comment: yes, the calling thread will block while the request is processed.  But you could create a method that `Tasks` this out....

Comment: A co-worker just pointed out that the session data might be loaded earlier in the pipeline (before you even ask for it) so awaiting the results would not make sense. If this is the case then I can see why there is no choice. I just want to make sure because I think it would be nice IF the session is stored over the wire on a db or state machine...

Comment: it depends on the session provider, I've built my own SQL session provider and the requests are processed as above, if any preemptive loading is occurring then it is implementation specific.

Comment: If i were to make that method it is still going to call a sync operation. My understanding of async is the entire stack needs to be async. Otherwise the thread will still block on operations such as these.

Comment: Oh, yeah I guess if you write your own session state provider you can control that.... Alright. Thanks!

Comment: If you were to write some code to Task/Thread/Async this out then yes the main call would be sync and blocking until execution is returned.  You could put a timeout on it perhaps.

Comment: I don't want to bloat this comment thread anymore so if someone can give an example of such a session state provider that can be implemented asynchronously (not blocking while waiting for db or state machine) please show it as an answer or explain why it isn't possible. The reasons i would still like to see it is because I'm not convinced this is possible via existing .NET session state APIs and because it would be more useful to others reading this question to see actually how to do this (if it is possible). PS: I realized you could do this outside of the existing .NET session state APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that reading from `Session` is always a CPU-only operating. Loading the session state happens as some early point in the pipeline. The loading step would indeed benefit from being asynchronous. Reading from the dictionary should stay as it always has been.

Unfortunately, the `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` class only has synchronous methods. Deriving from it would not be enough to achieve asynchronous loading. With a synchronous interface it is impossible to internally be async. `Task.Run(...).Wait();` would be the worst you could do here.

I don't know of a way of extending the ASP.NET pipeline easily but it might be possible. The pipeline already supports asynchronous steps. You might be able to run the loading step at a point in the pipeline where the synchronous session state loading step has not yet run. You load the session state asynchronously even before ASP.NET asks you to. When ASP.NET asks you just hand back the pre-calculated result.

Update: It is easier than I thought. The `HttpApplication` class has easy ways of attaching asynchronous event handlers to the pipeline. Just pick one that comes before the point where session state is loaded.

I don't know if this is worth it. Session state operations are usually very fast. Async IO makes the IO use more CPU time. The reason it is attractive on the server is that it unblocks threads. Makes more sense for seconds-long web-service calls then for a 1ms database call.

You can definitely mix sync and async in the same HTTP request, though. So no problem there. Just refrain from calling `Wait` or `Task.Run`.